# fl_chart bar chart clip out of chartbox

Tags: flutter, clip, fl-chart

I have been using fl_chart for making a barChart with usage over time (displaying : week/month/year).
I don't quite understand why when i pass from one to another display the bar does the following:

[fl_chart bug clip out of the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lbal.gif)

My chartwidget code :

```
String getWeekTitlesValues(double value) {
  switch (value.toInt()) {
    case 0:
      return 'Lun.';
    case 1:
      return 'Mar.';
    case 2:
      return 'Mer.';
    case 3:
      return 'Jeu.';
    case 4:
      return 'Ven.';
    case 5:
      return 'Sam.';
    case 6:
      return 'Dim.';
    default:
      return '';
  }
}

String getTitlesValues(String type, double value) {
  if (type == "week") {
    return getWeekTitlesValues(value);
  } else if (type == "month") {
    var val = value.round() + 1;
    if (val % 2 != 0) {
      return val.toString();
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  } else if (type == "year") {
    return (value.round() + 1).toString();
  }
  return "non defined";
}

//Classic (stateless) chart widget

class ChartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> listOfValues;
  final String type; //accepted types are "week", "month", "year"

  ChartWidget(this.listOfValues, this.type);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int maxValue = listOfValues.reduce(max);
    bool incoherentValue = false;
    if (type == "week" && listOfValues.length != 6) {
      incoherentValue = true;
    }
    if (type == "month" && listOfValues.length < 20) {
      incoherentValue = true;
    }
    if (type == "year" && listOfValues.length != 12) {
      incoherentValue = true;
    }
    //init interval
    int interval = (maxValue / 10).round();
    if (interval == 0 || listOfValues.isEmpty || incoherentValue) {
      return EmptyChartWidget(listOfValues, type);
    } else {
      int maxY;
      if (maxValue % interval == 0) {
        maxY = maxValue;
      } else {
        int valueToAdd = interval - (maxValue % interval);
        maxY = maxValue + valueToAdd;
      }
      //init BarGroup
      List<BarChartGroupData> barGroup = [];
      List<BarChartGroupData> newBarGroup = [];
      for (int i = 0; i < listOfValues.length; i++) {
        newBarGroup.add(BarChartGroupData(
          x: i,
          barRods: [
            BarChartRodData(
                y: listOfValues[i].toDouble(), colors: [Colors.blue])
          ],
          showingTooltipIndicators: [0],
        ));
      }
      barGroup = newBarGroup;
      //Return the chart
      return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.7,
        child: BarChart(
          BarChartData(
              gridData: FlGridData(
                  show: true,
                  getDrawingHorizontalLine: (double value) {
                    return FlLine(strokeWidth: 0.1);
                  },
                  drawHorizontalLine: true,
                  horizontalInterval:
                      interval.toDouble() //only one line on 2 is showed
                  ),
              minY: 0,
              alignment: BarChartAlignment.spaceBetween,
              maxY: maxY.toDouble(),
              barTouchData: BarTouchData(
                //This the writing (the value) on the top of the bars (don't touch it)
                enabled: false,
                touchTooltipData: BarTouchTooltipData(
                  tooltipBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                  tooltipPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  tooltipMargin: 0,
                  getTooltipItem: (
                    BarChartGroupData group,
                    int groupIndex,
                    BarChartRodData rod,
                    int rodIndex,
                  ) {
                    return BarTooltipItem(
                      rod.y.round().toString(),
                      TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 0),
                    ); //We can here add the value of each bar on top of it (by giving a size different than 0)
                  },
                ),
              ),
              titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                show: true,
                bottomTitles: SideTitles(
                  showTitles: true,
                  getTextStyles: (value) => const TextStyle(
                      //Bottom legend style
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(42, 42, 42, 0.7), //grey
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 13),
                  margin: 20,
                  getTitles: (double value) => getTitlesValues(type, value),
                ),
                leftTitles: SideTitles(
                  margin: 10,
                  showTitles: true,
                  getTitles: (double value) {
                    if (value.toInt() % interval == 0) {
                      String v = value
                          .toString()
                          .substring(0, value.toString().length - 2);
                      return v.toString();
                    } else {
                      return '';
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              borderData: FlBorderData(
                  show: true,
                  border: Border.symmetric(horizontal: BorderSide(width: 0.1))),
              barGroups: barGroup),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

class EmptyChartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> listOfValues;
  final String type; //accepted types are "week", "month", "year"

  EmptyChartWidget(this.listOfValues, this.type);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int maxValue = 60;
    int interval = 6;
    int maxY = 60;
    //init BarGroup
    List<BarChartGroupData> barGroup = [];
    List<BarChartGroupData> newBarGroup = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfValues.length; i++) {
      newBarGroup.add(BarChartGroupData(
        x: i,
        barRods: [
          BarChartRodData(y: listOfValues[i].toDouble(), colors: [Colors.blue])
        ],
        showingTooltipIndicators: [0],
      ));
    }
    barGroup = newBarGroup;
    //Return the chart
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1.7,
      child: BarChart(
        BarChartData(
            gridData: FlGridData(
                show: true,
                getDrawingHorizontalLine: (double value) {
                  return FlLine(strokeWidth: 0.1);
                },
                drawHorizontalLine: true,
                horizontalInterval:
                    interval.toDouble() //only one line on 2 is showed
                ),
            minY: 0,
            alignment: BarChartAlignment.spaceBetween,
            maxY: maxY.toDouble(),
            barTouchData: BarTouchData(
              //This the writing (the value) on the top of the bars (don't touch it)
              enabled: false,
              touchTooltipData: BarTouchTooltipData(
                tooltipBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                tooltipPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                tooltipMargin: 0,
                getTooltipItem: (
                  BarChartGroupData group,
                  int groupIndex,
                  BarChartRodData rod,
                  int rodIndex,
                ) {
                  return BarTooltipItem(
                    rod.y.round().toString(),
                    TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 0),
                  ); //We can here add the value of each bar on top of it (by giving a size different than 0)
                },
              ),
            ),
            titlesData: FlTitlesData(
              show: true,
              bottomTitles: SideTitles(
                showTitles: true,
                getTextStyles: (value) => const TextStyle(
                    //Bottom legend style
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(42, 42, 42, 0.7), //grey
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 13),
                margin: 5,
                getTitles: (double value) => getTitlesValues(type, value),
              ),
              leftTitles: SideTitles(
                margin: 10,
                showTitles: true,
                getTitles: (double value) {
                  if (value.toInt() % interval == 0) {
                    String v = value
                        .toString()
                        .substring(0, value.toString().length - 2);
                    return v.toString();
                  } else {
                    return '';
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            borderData: FlBorderData(
                show: true,
                border: Border.symmetric(horizontal: BorderSide(width: 0.1))),
            barGroups: barGroup),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The part of where the blue bar is made (who i think might be the culprit) :

```
barRods: [
          BarChartRodData(y: listOfValues[i].toDouble(), colors: [Colors.blue])
        ],
```

Thanks you in advance for your help !